# RandomChoice or RandomSample

Tags: random

I am trying to get multiple sets of random integers using `RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {4, 3}]`.

However, I always get repeats such as `{{6, 6, 7}, {8, 2, 7}, {1, 7, 1}, {8, 6, 5}}`. Can I please ask how to solve this?

Can I please also ask how to get all the possible integers without repeating numbers?

I am very new to *Mathematica* and can't find it in the examples.

Best

Comment: It's hard to avoid repeats in an array with 12 numbers if all you have are ten choices.

Comment: @J.M. - you've not seen vote counting in democratic districts...

Comment: I needed a laugh today; thanks for that, @ciao. :)